# Cannot make navbar responsive using media queries

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

When I try to put them in a different order it seems as it will change is there any specific order in it?
Here's some of my media query code:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width:700px){
        header{
            height: 8rem;  
        }

        .nav-brand{
            width: 3.5rem;
        }

        .nav-list{
            width: initial;
            height: initial;
            background-color: transparent;
            position: initial;
            top: initial;
            right: initial;
            flex-direction: row;
            transition: initial;
        }

        .menu-icons{
            display: none;
        }

        .nav-item{
            margin: 0 2.5rem;
        }

        .nav-link{
            color: #000000;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
        }
}
```

Comment: this will work on devices width > 700px and we can help more seeing your full css

Comment: You can use bootstrap to have responsive navbar : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: how do I post all code because when I do it says it's most likely all code so how do I show you all of it ? @Ziad Darwich

Comment: try to create a pen here codepen.io

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the navbar that's not responding to the media query, or is it the whole site?

I've forgotten to put in the viewport meta tag once or twice. Since it's usually handled by the frameworks and CMS platforms I use.
So that might be worth checking. :-)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

*Have a look at MDN web docs;* 
[*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

*Or CSS Tricks;*
[*https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/*](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)